# DropDownList MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing a edit operation on  a record in Grid . One of the column is DropDownValue.

When I go to Edit View , depending upon this dropdownvalue , I make few fields editable and readable.  And , One more point is here, I didnt select the dropdown Yet, But whatever its value selected before is the one which I should retrieve. I know I have to  use jQuery .But I didnt exact Syntax to do tht.

Here is my dropdown

```
<div id="dvstatus">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Study.StudyStatusId, Model.StatusSelectList, new { id = "ddlStatus" })
</div>
```

NOT SELECTED VALUE, BUT THE VALUE WITH WHICH IT IS LOADED

My requirement is how to get the dropdown value  item , when it is loaded onto .cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not referring to the selected value of the dropdown then just pass the value from the controller to your view using your model if you're using a strongly-typed view or pass it some other way like using ViewBag and just set the value when it's passed on view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field to save the initially loaded value. Eg

```
<div id="dvstatus">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Study.StudyStatusId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Study.StudyStatusId, Model.StatusSelectList, new { id = "ddlStatus" })
</div>
```

Then you can use java script to compare current value of the drop down and the value of the hidden field(which has the initial value).